# RavenDB 3.0 Index using Enumerable.Range

Tags: ravendb

I have the following index in RavenDB 3.0 (build 3599):

```
from pupil in docs.Pupils
from year in Enumerable.Range(pupil.BirthAcademicYear, 12)
select new {
    pupil.Upn,
    year
}
```

It is failing, returning the following error message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

This type of index worked in RavenDB 2.5. What has changed? Is this a new bug, is there a work-around?

I have tried changing the enumerable call to:

```
Enumerable.Range(pupil.BirthAcademicYear, 12).Select(i => (object)i)
```

This results in the error:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the index to be:

```
from pupil in docs.Pupils
from year in Enumerable.Select(Enumerable.Range(pupil.BirthAcademicYear, 12), (Func<int,object>)(u=> u))
select new {
    pupil.Upn,
    year
}
```

Comment: This causes exception: Unable to cast object of type '<RangeIterator>d__b8' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.